# Shared views for different namespaces in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We have two different namespaces in application - *admin* and *org*

They share some views, for example, *Event* edit form.

So I think the DRY way of doing to should be to place *event_form* to *shared/events/_form.html.slim*

But how to deal with dynamic link in form? For admin it should be **admin_event_path** and for org - **org_event_path**

Answer (score 2):

Pass it as argument in partial

```
= render 'shared/events/_form.html.slim', link_path: admin_event_path
```

Then in partial `form`

```
= link_to 'Some path', link_path
```

Give it a try